# Return factor associated with a numeric range defined in two columns

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, subset

Using a database with a numeric range defined by two columns `start` and `end`, I am trying to look up the factor, `code`, associated with a numeric value in a separate vector `identityCodes`.

```
database <- data.frame(start = seq(1, 150000000, 1000), 
                       end = seq(1000, 150000000, 1000),
                       code = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 15000, replace = TRUE), 
                                      sample(LETTERS, 15000, replace = TRUE)))

identityCodes <- sample(1:15000000, 1000)
```

I've come up with a method for finding the corresponding codes using a `for` loop and subsetting:

```
fun <- function (x, y) {
  z <- rep(NA, length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    z[i] <- as.character(y[y["start"] <= x[i] & y["end"] >= x[i], "code"])
  }
  return(z)
}

a <- fun(identityCodes, database)
```

But the method is slow, especially if I am to scale it:

```
system.time(fun(identityCodes, database))
user   system elapsed 
15.36    0.00   15.50
```

How can I identify the factors associated with each `identityCodes` faster? Is there a better way to go about this than using a for loop and subsetting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt using `data.table`.  Very fast - even though I am sure I am not leveraging it efficiently.

**Given function:**

```
# method 1
system.time(result1 <- fun(identityCodes, database))
 user  system elapsed 
 8.99    0.00    8.98
```

**Using `data.table`**

```
# method 2
require(data.table)

# x: a data.frame with columns start, end, code
# y: a vector with lookup codes
dt_comb <- function(x, y) {
  # convert x to a data.table and set 'start' and 'end' as keys
  DT <- setDT(x)
  setkey(DT, start, end)

  # create a lookup data.table where start and end are the identityCodes
  DT2 <- data.table(start=y, end=y)

  # overlap join where DT2 start & end are within DT start and end
  res <- foverlaps(DT2, DT[, .(start, end)], type="within")

  # store i as row number and key (for sorting later)
  res[, i:=seq_len(nrow(res))]
  setkey(res, i)

  # merge the joined table to the original to get codes
  final <- merge(res, DT, by=c("start", "end"))[order(i), .(code)]

  # export as character the codes
  as.character(final[[1]])
}

system.time(result2 <- dt_comb(x=database, y=identityCodes))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.08    0.00    0.08

identical(result1, result2)
[1] TRUE
```

edit:  trimmed a couple lines from the function

Comment: Nice! Can you add brief comments to your code? It would be extremely useful to see your example documented for `data.table` beginners like myself.

Comment: You bet!  Glad this is helpful.  Just added some explanatory comments

Answer (score 2):

This is about 45% faster on my machine:

```
result = lapply(identityCodes, function(x) {
  data.frame(identityCode=x, 
             code=database[database$start <= x & database$end >= x, "code"])
})

result = do.call(rbind, result)
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
  identityCode code
1      6836845   OK
2     14100352   RB
3      2313115   NK
4      8440671   XN
5     11349271   TI
6     14467193   VL
```

Comment: That it does, thank you! Comes in at about 9.4 seconds for me. Are there any faster ways to do this though? Perhaps involving a package or an avenue that doesn't involve subsetting? With a large dataset 9 seconds per 1000 cases adds up very quickly (e.g. 250k = ~38 minutes)

Comment: I'd be surprised if there wasn't something faster. Hopefully someone will provide a faster approach.